# selenium is able to find but unable to click on an unicode character

Tags: selenium-rc

I am having trouble getting selenium RC to click on a button. There is a button on a page that has the character "pi" on it and I am trying to click on it. The html code looks something like this

```
<div id="abc">
<a class="my keys one" keystring="Pi" keyvalue="π"
π
</a>
</div>
```

This is what I have done so far -
selenium.click("//div[@id='abc']/a[1]");

This returns an OK but on the page, when I see visually, the button is not clicked (on click, the page has to do something).

I have tried other stuff like getting the Attribute and making it click on it, but doesnt work-
selenium.click(selenium.getAttribute("//div[@id='abc']/a[1]@keystring"));

I have even tried converting the above selenium.getAttribute to a unicode value and then clicking on it. That does not work too.

Also, I added a line to check if at least selenium thinks the character pi is present on the page. I used the unicode of pi-
selenium.isElementPresent("\u03c0");
On eclipse, when I run it, this shows up- isElementPresent[?, ] on session...
and returns a false.

I am stumped. Can anyone please point to me what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i thin this may help you.

```
selenium.click("//a[@class='my keys one']");
or
selenium.click("xpath=//a[@class='my keys one'"]");

if it is not workin use css path.
```

Answer (score 0):

I a similar issue.  My button has a "black down-pointing triangle" on it and none of the other attributes are unique (the "class", "id", and "role" are reused over and over on the same page).  The only unique thing I have is a "value" that is a symbol.

```
value="▼ "
```

I, too, would like to know if there is a way to click on this button.